# i am unable to connect to oracle database using servlet and jdbc connections.Getting 404 and 500 errors on web page

Tags: java

LoginServlet.java:
this is the login servlet where oracle data base connection is imported.

```
package com.ts;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.util.MyConnection;

@WebServlet("/login")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Connection con = null;
        con = MyConnection.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        String sql = "select * from users where userid = ? and pwd = ?"
                + "";
        String user = request.getParameter("userid");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pwd");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html>");

        if(con!=null)
            System.out.println("Connection NOT Successful...");
        //System.out.println("established");
        System.out.println("user"+user);
        try {
            preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, user);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, pass);
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            if(resultSet.next())
            {
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("WelcomeServlet");
                    rd.forward(request, response);              
            }
            else
            {
                out.println("<body bgcolor=red text=yellow>");
                out.println("<h1>Invalid Credentials</h1>");
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Login.html");
                rd.include(request, response);              
            }                       
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        finally
        {
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {          
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request,response);   
    }
}
```

MYConnection.java:

```
package com.util;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.SynchronizedSymbolTable;

public class MyConnection {

    public static Connection getConnection()
    {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522:XE","system","system");
            if(connection!=null)
                System.out.println("Connection Successful...");
            return connection;

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Look at the error log to see what is happend

Comment: Are you sure your port number is 1522, i think default port is 1521  ?

Answer (score 0):

are you using the oralce database express edition ? if yes,oralce database express edition's default port is 1521 if you don't change the default port,not the 1522,you can reference this link,http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/howto-connect-xe-095131.html